# Fast Android JSON/BSON/DOM database

Tags: android, database, nosql

I'm looking for a fast Android embedded database that would work well with JSON documents.

I want to quickly load large number of json documents on memory and have an option to insert/update any of in a reasonably performant way.

I'm testing with a 8MB big json which includes about 8000 or json documents similar to the one below. I can afford to load the whole 8MB json file in less than 0.5 second on iOS but performance on Android Nexus 5 doing something naive like that is terrible.

Example:

- org.json.JSONObject ~ 120s
- Jackson - new ObjectMapper().readValue( new FileInputStream(...), (new HashMap()).getClass()) takes 5 minutes.

How could I speed this up?

I've also tried Couchbase lite/mobile. Write performance is terrible. Wasn't even able to write them all into the db.

I'm about to try sqlite ( i want  to see if I can get away with flattening the json by writing the most commonly used fields in the columns and serializing the rest in a BLOB.
Any experience with LevelDB?

Here is an example JSON object in the file. The whole 8MB files contains an array of around 8000 of similar ones.

```
{
   "remoteid": "3C3C9732-1375-44A0-B989-377AA83CC767",
   "#steps_profile": 1950567011,
   "activeDuration": 388,
   "privacy_groups": [
    "public",
    "friends",
    "family"
   ],
   "type": "steps",
   "meta": {
    "uuid": "V_69299348-D5E4-4C04-B19D-3AF323F01669",
    "ip": "50.78.97.166",
    "client_version": "2.21.141"
   },
   "version": 7,
   "timestamp": 1404233985001,
   "id": "1950567011",
   "timezone": -7,
   "distance": 329.1365051269531,
   "created": 1404198438260,
   "value": 721,
   "calories": 932.7751237542399,
   "user_id": "7001",
   "client_id": "com.azumio.iphone.argus",
   "end": 1404233985000,
   "live": true,
   "privacy": 1,
   "steps": 721,
   "modified": 1404235833983,
   "goals": {"value.sum.daily": 8000},
   "walkCalories": 25.953123754240004,
   "start": 1404198000000,
   "basalCalories": 906.8219999999999
 }
```